# maven-rar-plugin includes all Dependencies with configuration set to false

Tags: java, maven

I am using maven-rar-plugin and following is my configuration in POM file. `includeDependencies` is set to false. But all the dependent and dependent project's sub dependencies are all packaged into rar.

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-rar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <raXmlFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/ra.xml</raXmlFile>
        <includeDependencies>false</includeDependencies>
        <archive>
            <addMavenDescriptor>true</addMavenDescriptor>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I cannot use exclusion in dependencies as it would lead to compilatin errors.

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fi.ps</groupId>
        <artifactId>frm-fl</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>   
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Is this a bug in the Maven plugin or is there a different way of configuring for rar packaging?

Comment: Where is this `includeDependencies` parameter defined? I cannot find in the documentation: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-rar-plugin/rar-mojo.html .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no [`includeDependencies`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-rar-plugin/rar-mojo.html) parameter for the `maven-rar-plugin` and, from reading [the source code](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/blob/trunk/maven-rar-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/rar/RarMojo.java#L331-L351), it isn't currently possible to exclude dependencies of the project. A possible work-around would be to declare the dependencies to exclude with the `provided` scope: they will be present during compilation but excluded when building the RAR file.

But why do you want to exclude dependencies in the first place? The `maven-rar-plugin` is used to build a Resource Adapter Archive file for the Java 2 Connector Architecture. Dependencies are supposed to be included, otherwise it won't work. Beware that, [as stated in the FAQ](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-rar-plugin/faq.html), this plugin does not create compressed file like WinRar.

Comment: These dependencies are 3rd party jars and are open to change. Packaging into rar is not ideal. But i need these dependencies for compilation.

Comment: @Rajath But are you _really_ using J2C? The RAR you created is NOT a WinRAR file. For a possible work-around, see my edit.

Comment: You should not check the current trunk of the source code for documentation only the published web site contains the correct documentation state https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-rar-plugin/ for released versions of the plugins.

Comment: I am using JCA, Resource Adapter. Yes its .rar file not WinRAR.
Using <scope>provided</scope> did the trick. Dependent jars are not packaged in .rar file. Thank you.